# Using jQuery in Wordpress inline script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, session

I need to load a bootstrap modal when a page loads and was trying to do it the easy way of adding an inline script to handle the call. For the life of me I cannot find any information whether or not this is even a possibility.

FYI I've enqueued jQuery properly and use it in plenty of other scripts.

Keep getting `jQuery is not defined` no matter what combination of things I try.

Here's a little snippet of something I've tried

```
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['form-failed'])): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    (function($){
       $('#request-info').modal('show');
    })(jQuery);
    -->
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**If this is not a possibility, what would be the best way to get a modal to show on page load based on a session variable?**

Comment: You should enqueue this snippet also so it loads after jQuery.js does. Likely that you are running this code before the jQuery library is loaded

Comment: You're probably right. Seems strange that content would load before the enqueues are fired.

Comment: Not really if enqueues are set to load at bottom of body

Comment: All of my enqueues are being handled with Wordpress add_action() function.

Comment: Understand that but if template loads the scripts at end of body then code in the content would be before those scripts

Comment: You're right!! It works!  I see jQuery.js and Bootstrap.js were being loaded in the body. I changed them to load in the head problem solved. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Shame to load in head just for that one snippet. Pages load more efficiently with scripts in body

Comment: I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Use enqueue functions to add that snippet with jquery dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185624/discussion-between-rager-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('load', function (){
    $('#request-info').modal('show')
})
```

Comment: Of course you should have loaded the jQuery library before this script is loaded/executed, I don't know if you are loading previously in a header script tag for example should work just fine...